# Sharepoint 2010 site stopped working. Database “needs upgrading”. Upgrade fails

Tags: error, content-database

One of my Sharepoint 2010 Site Collections has stopped functioning this morning and presents the following in the browser.

> Server error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=177673

When I look at the "Manage Databases Upgrade Status" for the content database in Central Administration, it tells me

> Database is too old and upgrade is required

Other content databases are fine and the other site collections work.

After Googling, several sites have suggested to run:

```
psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
```

But this also fails on task 2 of 4 saying

> An exception of type Microsoft.Sharepoint.Administration.SPUpdatedConcurrencyException was thrown. Additional exception information: An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object SPUpgradeSession Name=Upgrade-20130307-113655-410 was updated by MYDOMAIN\Administrator, in the PSCONFIG (7228) process, on machine MYSERVER.

I am running out of options, short of doing a restore from backup which isn't the preferred solution as this is our company intranet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing the follwing and then re-running the upgrade command above:

- stsadm -o setproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running -pv No
- IISReset
- Restart the Windows SharePoint Timer